# My application has application.yml in the resources folder however Spring boot application is complaining that application.properties is not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

My application has application.yml in the main and test resources folder however application (Spring boot 2.4 with Maven) is complaining that application.properties is not found.

Below is the error.

```
2021-07-08 04:37:33.381 ERROR   --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@bd4ee01] to prepare test instance [com.test.SomeTests@6a7aa675]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:187)
```

I have tried to find solution online but could not able to find one. Please help.

Comment: It smells like you have a test that's explicitly specifying `application.properties` somewhere instead of using the Boot infrastructure.

Comment: Hi @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thank you for your quick response. you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a sufficient description for your problem, where did you put the application.yml file ? if you are in a maven projet project, you should put it under `src/main/resources` folder.

Also I'm not sure if spring is able to interpret **.yml** file extension of your file, try to change it to **application.yaml** instead.

**Note from [spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html:)** :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify your application properties location by setting the program arguments with as :

```
--spring.config.location=your_properties_path
```